# Listing elements by geolocation

Tags: geolocation, maps

I am trying to create a listing website, though i am a newby in programming i started self-learning.
My question:
I want to list elements(restaurants) on the homepage by the nearest from user who entered my website,
Could you please advise something or maybe a ready script or code

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: Sorry, but this question is *way* to broad for our site. Can you explain what you *can* do right now, what your next step should be and where exactly you are stuck?

Comment: Hello,I apologize for my bad explanation,

Comment: Rhe only thing i need is to understand how to i list my items on the fron page by geolocation ( sort items) for example nearest restaurants in the area

Comment: We cannot remotely read your mind or your code. We still need to know what you **can** do of all that. Do you  *have* a list of restaurants? Do they *have* geocodes? *Can* you display them in a list? *Can* you order that list by something, for example name? Do you *have* the current location? *Can* you calculate the distance between two locations? *Can* you use that value to order the list? If the answer to all were 'yes', you'd not be here. But we need to know which answers are 'no', otherwise we don't know what to help you with.